# how to save changed pitch audio file to sd card android

Tags: android, audiotrack

In my android application I want to change the pitch of an audio file and save it to sd card.

I am using sonic ndk [link](https://github.com/waywardgeek/sonic-ndk) for changing pitch of my audio file but I am unable to save the changed audio file.


Is there any way to save this changed pitch audio file? Thanks in advance

Below is the code that I am using for my audio modification and save.

```
 public class SonicTest extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button saveBtn;
    private int bufferSize=0;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);                      
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        saveBtn = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void play(View view)
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() 
        {
            public void run()
            {
                final EditText speedEdit = findViewById(R.id.speed);
                final EditText pitchEdit = findViewById(R.id.pitch);
                final EditText rateEdit = findViewById(R.id.rate);
                float speed = Float.parseFloat(speedEdit.getText().toString());
                float pitch = Float.parseFloat(pitchEdit.getText().toString());
                float rate = Float.parseFloat(rateEdit.getText().toString());
                AndroidAudioDevice device = new AndroidAudioDevice(22050, 1);
                Sonic sonic = new Sonic(22050, 1);
                byte samples[] = new byte[4096];
                byte modifiedSamples[] = new byte[2048];
                InputStream soundFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.talking);
               // InputStream soundFile = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.sample);


                int bytesRead;

                if(soundFile != null) {
                    sonic.setSpeed(speed);
                    sonic.setPitch(pitch);
                    sonic.setRate(rate);
                    do {
                        try {
                            bytesRead = soundFile.read(samples, 0, samples.length);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            return;
                        }
                        if(bytesRead > 0) {
                            sonic.putBytes(samples, bytesRead);
                        } else {
                            sonic.flush();
                        }
                        int available = sonic.availableBytes(); 
                        if(available > 0) {
                            if(modifiedSamples.length < available) {
                                modifiedSamples = new byte[available*2];
                            }

                            sonic.receiveBytes(modifiedSamples, available);
                            device.writeSamples(modifiedSamples, available);
                        }
                    } while(bytesRead > 0);
                    device.flush();

                }
            }
        } ).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        LinkedList<byte[]>linkedList = AndroidAudioDevice.list;
        for (int i=0; i<linkedList.size(); i++){
            bufferSize = bufferSize+linkedList.get(i).length;
        }
        byte[]buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        int k=0;
        for (int i=0 ; i< linkedList.size(); i++){

            for(int j=0; j<linkedList.get(i).length; j++){
                buffer[k]=linkedList.get(i)[j];
                k++;
            }
            Log.v("Buffer array length",""+k);
        }

        File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"demo.mp3");
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(buffer);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

package org.vinuxproject.sonic;

```
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.AudioTrack;
import android.os.Environment;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class AndroidAudioDevice
{
    AudioTrack track;
    static int bufferLength;
    public static   LinkedList<byte[]>list= new LinkedList<>();

    private int findFormatFromChannels(int numChannels)
    {
        switch(numChannels) {
        case 1: return AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_MONO;
        case 2: return AudioFormat.CHANNEL_OUT_STEREO;
        default: return -1; // Error
        }
    }

    public AndroidAudioDevice(int sampleRate, int numChannels)
    {
        int format = findFormatFromChannels(numChannels);
        int minSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(sampleRate, format, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);        
        track = new AudioTrack( AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, sampleRate, 
            format, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, 
            minSize*4, AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);
        track.play();



    }      

    public void flush()
    {
        track.flush();
    }

    public void writeSamples(byte[] samples, int length) 
    {
        bufferLength = bufferLength+length;
        track.write( samples, 0, length);
        list.add(samples);
    }

}
```

Comment: "I am unable to save the changed audio file" - What have you tried? Where is your code? Do you get an error? If you do - what error and where is the stack trace?

Comment: @TDG I have added my code for audio pitch updating and saving to Sdcard

Comment: Any luck on the solution? @Sandeepdhiman